# ++, last & init faster than :, head & tail?

Tags: haskell, primes

Given these two ways of writing a function that finds all primes up to a specific number:

```
primes1 = iterate
    (\ps -> ps ++ [([x |
        x <- [last ps + 1..],
        all (\p -> x `mod` p /= 0) ps] !! 0)])
    [2]

primesTo1 :: Integer -> [Integer]
primesTo1 n = init $ head $ dropWhile (\p -> last p <= n) primes1

primes2 = iterate
    (\ps -> ([x |
            x <- [head ps + 1..],
            all (\p -> x `mod` p /= 0) ps] !! 0)
        : ps)
    [2]

primesTo2 :: Integer -> [Integer]
primesTo2 n = tail $ head $ dropWhile (\p -> head p <= n) primes2
```

Why is `primesTo1` a lot faster than `primesTo2`, even though the different functions used; `primesTo1` uses `++`, `last` & `init` instead of `:`, `head` & `tail` used in `primesTo2`.

Output of `ghci` with `:set +s`:

```
*Main> primesTo1 10000
...
(0.51 secs, 124779776 bytes)
*Main> primesTo2 10000
...
(3.30 secs, 570648032 bytes)
```

Compiled with `ghc -O2`:

```
$ time ./primes1
...
./primes1  0.06s user 0.00s system 68% cpu 0.089 total
$ time ./primes2
...
./primes2  0.28s user 0.00s system 98% cpu 0.283 total
```

---

**Note:** I'm not looking for an optimal prime number generator for Haskell, I'm just confused by the speed differences of the two functions.

Comment: `primes1` scans primes bottom-up, `primes2` does it top-down. The latter is a really really bad slow way to filter out composite numbers.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: There are far more numbers divisible by 2 or 3 than by 997.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think n.m. already said that.

Comment: I was just expanding on that, saying why it is a slow approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by the "n.m.", the reason for this is that `primes2` first tries to divide by the largest found primes, while `primes1` starts with the lowest.

So first reversing the list of current primes, before using them in `all` is actually faster than both `primes1` and `primes2`:

```
primes3 = iterate
    (\ps -> ([x |
            x <- [head ps + 1..],
            all (\p -> x `mod` p /= 0) $ reverse ps] !! 0)
        : ps)
    [2]

primesTo3 :: Integer -> [Integer]
primesTo3 n = tail $ head $ dropWhile (\p -> head p <= n) primes3
```

`ghci` speed with `10000` as argument:

```
*Main> primesTo3 10000
...
(0.41 secs, 241128512 bytes)
```

and compiled with `ghc -O2`:

```
$ time ./primes3
...
./primes  0.05s user 0.00s system 24% cpu 0.209 total
```

Comment: try ``all (\p -> rem x p /= 0) $ takeWhile (\p-> p*p <= x) $ reverse ps``.

Comment: With `ghci`: `(0.13 secs, 177274752 bytes)`, compiled: `0.01s user 0.00s system 82% cpu 0.018 total`

Comment: try two size points, say n=10000 and n=20000. Then check [the empirical order of growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) `n^a` of your algorithm at that range, with `a = logBase (n2/n1) (t2/t1)` (for 10k vs 20k, `logBase 2 (t2/t1)`). :) also try it for your original algo. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you're "not looking for an optimal prime number generator for Haskell" but you were still interested in "speed differences of the two functions". So here's few more syntactic manipulations on your corrected function, `primes3`, which adds primes by `(:)`, in reversed order, and reverses them for testing each time,

```
primes3 :: [[Integer]]
primes3 = iterate
    (\ps -> ([x |
            x <- [head ps + 1..],
            all (\p -> x `mod` p /= 0) $
                takeWhile (\p-> p*p <= x) $ reverse ps] !! 0)
        : ps)                            -- ^^^^^^^^^^
    [2]
```

This code can be modified (although this won't change the efficiency):

```
primes3b :: [[Integer]]
primes3b = iterate
    (\ps -> ([x |
            x <- [head ps + 1..],
            all (\p -> x `mod` p /= 0) $
                takeWhile (\p-> p*p <= x) $ map head $ primes3b ] !! 0)
        : ps)                            -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [2]
```

isn't it? and that is equivalent to (notice the type change)

```
primes4 :: [Integer]
primes4 = map head $ iterate
    (\ps -> ([x |
            x <- [head ps + 1..],
            all (\p -> x `mod` p /= 0) $
                takeWhile (\p-> p*p <= x) primes4 ] !! 0)
        : ps)                          -- ^^^^^^^
    [2]
```

which is the same as

```
primes5 :: [Integer]
primes5 = iterate
    (\p -> head [x | x <- [p + 1..],
                 all (\p -> x `mod` p /= 0) $
                   takeWhile (\p-> p*p <= x) primes5 ] 
           ) -- nothing!
    2
```

or, a little bit faster,

```
primes6 :: [Integer]
primes6 = 2 : iterate
    (\p -> head [x | x <- [p + 2, p + 4..],
                 all (\p -> x `mod` p /= 0) $ tail $
                   takeWhile (\p-> p*p <= x) primes6 ] )
    3           -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Lastly, (and with considerable gain in speed and even [empirical orders of growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) it turns out) - why add just one number at each iteration, having spent work to fetch the primes to test by? We can work by portions between consecutive squares of primes. The fetched primes list is of the *same length* for these segments, and that length increases by 1 from segment to segment:

```
primes7 :: [Integer]
primes7 = concatMap snd $ iterate 
              (\((n,p:ps@(q:_)),_) -> ((n+1,ps),
                       [x | let lst = take n $ tail primes7,
                            x <- [p*p + 2, p*p + 4..q*q-2],
                            all ((/= 0).rem x) lst]))
              ((1,tail primes7),[2,3,5,7])
```

which actually express the *optimal trial division* sieve.